# How can I export tables in Excel file using ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: excel, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

My View consists of multiple tables, and I am looking to Export multiple tables from View in Excel file. My current function only helps me to export 1 table.

Can any one help me to complete this code so that multiple tables can be exported?

1. Report VM

```
public class ReportVM
    {
        public string ScenName { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }

        public string CreateTickYes { get; set; }
        public int TickYes { get; set; }

        public string RegionName { get; set; }
        public int RegionCount { get; set; }

        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public int ChatCountUser { get; set; }
    }
```

2. Action Method to export

```
public FileContentResult DownloadReport(DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {

            //var uName = User.Identity.Name;

            var fileDownloadName = String.Format("Report.xlsx");
            const string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";


            // Pass your ef data to method


            ExcelPackage package = GenerateExcelFile(db.Chats.Where(x => System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ChatCreateDateTime) >= start && System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ChatCreateDateTime) <= end)
                            .GroupBy(a => a.ScenarioList).Select(b => new ReportVM()
                            {
                                ScenName = b.Key,
                                Count = b.Count()
                            }).ToList());


            var fsr = new FileContentResult(package.GetAsByteArray(), contentType);
            fsr.FileDownloadName = fileDownloadName;

            return fsr;

        }

        private static ExcelPackage GenerateExcelFile(IEnumerable<ReportVM> datasource)
        {

            ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();


            //Create the worksheet 
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet 1");

            
            // Sets Headers
            ws.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Scenario";
            ws.Cells[1, 2].Value = "No.Of Chats";


            // Inserts Data
            for (int i = 0; i < datasource.Count(); i++)
            {
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 1].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).ScenName;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, 2].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).Count;
            }

            //Sheet2
            


            // Format Header of Table
            using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells["A1:B1"])
            {

                rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid; //Set Pattern for the background to Solid 
                rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Gold); //Set color to DarkGray 
                rng.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.Black);
            }
            return pck;
        }
```

So, now it export data for Table GroubBy = ScenarioList. I want to also include another column in groupBy = Username. So when Export data, Excel  file should contain 2 Sheets. 1 for Table ScenarioList, and 2nd for Table Username.

Help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can do it by javascript if your data displaying on view mean in form of html.

Comment: Are you trying to export it to a file for download or display?

Comment: I am trying export it to excel file for download. Currently it downloads group by scenario, and I am looking to download another table group by Username

Answer (score 0):

You need create div/table under which put all tables and then by using below javascript function. Please call this javascript function on button click on same page which have all data. This is working for me which I already used in my project.

```
function DownloadToExcel() {

var htmls = $("#compareBodyContent")[0].innerHTML; // this main element under which 
                                                    //all you data
var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,';
var template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>';
var base64 = function (s) {
    return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
};

var format = function (s, c) {
    return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
        return c[p];
    })
};

var ctx = {
    worksheet: 'Worksheet',
    table: '<table>' + htmls + '</table>'
}

var compareLink = document.createElement("a");
compareLink.download = "Compare_Test.xls";
compareLink.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
compareLink.click();
}
```

Hope this will help you. Let me know if you have any question on this.

Comment: @ManjoKS thank you, java script does work and does export all tables from view. Though all tables are exported on Worksheet. How can I export each table in seperate Worksheet.  Like Scenario  on Sheet 1, Usernames on Sheet 2 and so on. Help is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Good to know. You can find in Google to export in separate worksheet. I have given idea, you need to work around it.